# could there be any disadvantages to this kind of URL validation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, validation, urlfetch

In some parts of my site, I'll allow users to enter an URL. I'm working on appengine, so what I was thinking, is to validate it like this.

```
try
    response = urlfetch.fetch(url,follow_redirects=True, deadline=1)
    if not response.status_code==200:
       raise SomeCustomException
except: Exception as e:
    my_exception_handling_code(e)
```

advantages

- checks for url pattern automatically
- also makes sure that the url isn't broken and the loading time is no longer than 1s, helping to ensure a good user experience when clicking a link on my site.

possible disadvantages I can see:

- the request has to wait for the fetch to complete. This will probably not be a very big deal, as there are very few occasions where users can enter URL's (currently only on signup).

Comment: Why aren't you using `urlparse` module?  Loading a page from a URL doesn't tell you much, since link liveness comes and goes.  Since a link can go dead immediately after you checked it, what are you hoping to accomplish with this?  What's the use case?

Comment: You are right, links may break immediately after being entered, and links may take longer to load, but this will not happen in the majority of cases, neither will it be the case that the URL is only reachable from a certain subnetwork. The site is built for a less tech-savvy audience, so I don't expect people to enter too much weird stuff in there (I know they can). Links will eventually break, but I'm hoping it will keep the majority of the avoidable 404's and slow-loading pages out.

Comment: " The site is built for..." Please actually **update** the question with a  description of the use case.  Comments are difficult to read and integrate with the rest of the question.  Also.  Other sites allow embedding links in content.  (This one, for example).  What have you seen in practice?  There are a variety of techniques for optional link-checking.  Would those be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad idea.  As S. Lott pointed, url might not be available now.  Or it might be available only from some specific subnetwork.  Or it gets more than 1 second to load it.  Just don't do this.  Use a traditional approach, e.g. [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html).

Answer (score 1):

If a user of your site figured out that you poll a URL every time they post one they might be able to exploit it for other purposes, like voting in a poll, or racking up pageviews.